# Create file JSON online and get URL

Tags: android, json

From string JSON, I want to create a URL to display that string JSON.

Do you know a website which supports this!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/). Select language `JavaScript`. I have created a sample [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3064729). You can also get the JSON in raw format.

---

The following SO post specifies an alternate to gist:

[Json-Viewer: data in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812517/json-viewer-data-in-url)

Answer (score -1):

You have to create the web service which create the data in to JSON format. Most probably .net framework do this. So use .net web service that create the Web Service and gives url. then you are able to use that url to parse it.

Comment: I want to up file json in my PC to internet and get link access direct content of that file..I want to operate parse file JSON online :D