# Upload JSON file and get a dynamic view able link for free

Tags: android, json, cloud, storage

Is there anyway without any cost to upload a JSON file and get a viewable link dynamically through which we can view the text in our JSON file in a browser. I want my android app to access my JSON file dynamically online. Kindly suggest me a way through which I can.

Comment: Upload the file on google drive or box - you can share a link direct to the file

Comment: @barny It doesn't works when I upload it on the Google drive and add the shareable link in my code. The app crashes. I guess there is no preview of the .JSON format file available when it is attached with the drive. I guess that is the reason, or not?

Comment: use pastebin or GitHub or any hosting service

Comment: @Zakharhabib
Please see this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372313/523118

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create file JSON online and get URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372105/create-file-json-online-and-get-url)